# How to view a JSON object constructed using objects before using the post()

Tags: java, json, api, rest-assured

Hellloo...
I'm constructing a JSON object using JAVA eclipse and that object will be used in the

```
given()
.body(constructed)
.post("url")
```

I wanted to review the constructed JSON object before sending it in the post.

can you guys tell is there any way that the request sent will be seen.?

Answer (score 0):

you may use fiddler tool to monitor the requests and response (network traffic) from your system. Link to install fiddler http://www.telerik.com/fiddler
you can debug traffic from PC and mobile devices and check that the proper cookies, headers, and cache directives are transferred between the client and server.